# Correctly package plugin that contains open-source licences

Tags: php, open-source, licensing

I'm building a project that uses source from a project that's been built from a project that uses code under MIT and GNU licences.

What steps do I need to take to make sure that the source has the correct licence files in the right places?

The project in question is a php plugin for another app, not an executable.

Comment: Are you linking to these code bases? Are you using some of their code or is your plugin a modification to these, or what?

Comment: Yep I'm linking to their code base, the current files come with a LICENCES file which contains the MIT and GNU, just wondering how I should package these inside my plugin?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing or legal issues, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274963/questions-about-licensing/274964#274964) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139804/can-licensing-questions-ever-be-on-topic) for details, and the [help] for more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mix code it must comply with both licenses, which generally means they must be compatible. I believe MIT is pretty easy to merge with GPL as long as you obey the following:

> The MIT License
>
> Copyright (c)
>
> Permission is hereby granted, free of
> charge, to any person obtaining a copy
> of this software and associated
> documentation files (the "Software"),
> to deal in the Software without
> restriction, including without
> limitation the rights to use, copy,
> modify, merge, publish, distribute,
> sublicense, and/or sell copies of the
> Software, and to permit persons to
> whom the Software is furnished to do
> so, subject to the following
> conditions:
>
> The above copyright notice and this
> permission notice shall be included in
> all copies or substantial portions of
> the Software.

Which seems to imply the only requirement is to place the license file with an "substantial" portions of code. It should NOT override the GPL though because the language of GPL is more strict and requires the MIT portions to become GPL (in your version). In other words your whole software must be GPL.

Comment: Note to potential downvoters. The GPL can be controvertial for some people. Do not simply downvote because you do not like what is being said. GPL code has certain requirements and if you don't like them then don't re-use the software.